# Writing a function that returns a strings position in a list (C code)

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program (in C) that takes in names from the command line, puts them in a linked list, and returns a number that corresponds with said name's position in the list. If the name isn't in the list, the program returns a -1. For example, If I run my program as

```
./a Chris Sale Jay Cutler Kermit Bob
```

The output should be

```
Chris is at position 1

Sale is at position 2

Jay is at position 3
```

and so on.

And then the output for Big Al (in my code) would be

```
Big Al is at position -1
```

I have all the code except for the function that returns the position of the name that is inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
char *name;
struct node *next;
} Node;

// function signatures

int position(char *, Node *);
Node *addEnd(char *, Node *);

// code for position goes here (what I need help with)
int position(char *c, Node *list) {
    int num = -1;
    Node *temp = list;  
    while(temp != NULL) {
            for(num = 1; num < temp; num++) {
                if(strcmp(temp->name, c) == 0) {
                    return num;
                }
            }
        temp = temp->next;
        }
    return num;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Node *addEnd(char *n, Node *list) {
    Node *newOne = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newOne->name = malloc(strlen(n)+1);
    strcpy(newOne->name, n);
    newOne->next = NULL;

    if (list == NULL)
        return newOne;
    Node *temp = list;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = newOne;
    return list;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Node *list = NULL;
    int a;

    printf("Adding people to the list\n\n");
    for (a=1; a<argc; a++) 
        list = addEnd(argv[a], list);

    printf("Finding positions of people in the list\n\n");
    for (a=1; a<argc; a++) 
        printf("%s is at position %d\n", argv[a], position(argv[a], list));

    printf("\nChecking for people that don't exist\n");
    printf("Big Al is at position %d\n", position("Big Al", list));

    return 0;
}
```

Currently I get a compiling error:

```
where.c: In function ‘position’:
where.c:20:20: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
   for(num = 0; num < temp; num++) {
```

And I know I cannot make this comparison, but I have no idea what to do from here. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fail to find that line `for(num = 0; num < temp; num++) {` in the code you show.

Comment: you are already iterating through the list with, while(temp != NULL), and temp=temp->next, why do you need that **for** loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `for` loop. You iterate the linked list using a `while` loop until it doesn't point to a next node.

```
int position(char *c, Node *list) {
    int num = 1;
    Node *temp = list;  
    while(temp != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(temp->name, c) == 0) {
            return num;
        }
        num++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I forgot that my while loop will walk the list without a need for another loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your program runs fine. You do not need the **for** loop in **position** function. You are already iterating through the list. All you need to do is increment the num variable in your position function.

Just add num++ in your position function. Look at the following code snipet:

```
int position(char *c, Node *list) {
    int num = 1;
    Node *temp = list;  
    while(temp != NULL) {

                if(strcmp(temp->name, c) == 0) {
                    return num;
                }
                num++;

                temp = temp->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This code won't return -1 when the string is not present in the list, nor will it return the right position since it starts from -1.

Comment: Yes, right, it wont return -1 when the string is not present. Well, nor does your original program. I missed out on that. I will modify it accordingly. It does return right position, however.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the for loop and comparing a pointer to a int doesn't make sense, other than that you almost got it correct :D

```
int position(char *c, Node *list) 
{
    int num = 0;
    Node *temp = list;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->name, c) == 0)
        {
            return num;
        }

        num++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return -1;
}
```